# Weka, how convert database mysql table to arff file

Tags: java, weka

which class of Weka should I use to convert a table of a database into a file compatible for Weka ARFF?

I found on the net how to convert an ARFF file in the database, but not the reverse.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to export from database to `csv` format. Then you can use in Weka Tool it like arff. It can be more easier.

Also you can look at this **[topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438743/export-a-sql-database-into-a-csv-file-and-use-it-with-weka)** and answer.